# R: how to create a scatter plot with 3 columns as one continuance x factor?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataframe with ID as rows and several parameters for each ID as columns, among those parameters are columns of "weight at age 1", "weight at age 2", "weight at age 3" and "population".
For each population, I would like to create its own scatter plot with age as x aes and weight as y aes, ideally, all population are layered on the same final graph.
How do I do that?
tnx!!

an example of my data:

| ID | POPULATION | weight at age 1 | weight at age 2 | weight at age 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 13.37 | 14.15 | 17.36 |
| 2 | A | 5.19 | 15.34 | NA |
| 3 | B | 7.68 | 6.92 | 19.42 |
| 4 | B | 6.96 | 15.12 | 36.39 |
| 5 | C | 10.35 | 8.86 | 26.33 |

Comment: Hello and welcome to stack overflow. Here, we try to answer programming questions, and from reading your post you seem to have a data visualisation problem instead of a programming problem. Please re-phrase your post to be about programming and include some reproducible code that you have tried to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I attempted to interpret your question.

```
library(tidyverse)
#pivot data into long format

df <- data.frame(
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
                ID = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L),
        POPULATION = c("A", "A", "B", "B", "C"),
   weight.at.age.1 = c(13.37, 5.19, 7.68, 6.96, 10.35),
   weight.at.age.2 = c(14.15, 15.34, 6.92, 15.12, 8.86),
   weight.at.age.3 = c(17.36, NA, 19.42, 36.39, 26.33)
) %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = weight.at.age.1:weight.at.age.3, 
               names_to = 'age', 
               values_to = 'weight') %>% 
  mutate(age = str_remove(age, 'weight.at.age.'))

#plot data
ggplot(data = df, 
       mapping = aes(x = age, 
                     y = weight))+
  geom_point()+
  facet_wrap(~POPULATION)
```

[image: sample]

Comment: thank u!
I did that with a few changes:

...  pivot_longer(cols = weight.at.age.1:weight.at.age.3, 
               names_to = 'age', 
               values_to = 'weight') %>% 
  mutate(age = str_remove(age, 'weight.at.age.'))

#plot data
ggplot(data = df, 
       mapping = aes(x = age, 
                     y = weight), color=POPULATION)+
  geom_smooth()

Answer (score 1):

You can reshape your dataframe into a long-format, and then use `facet_wrap` to create one plot for each population:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- expand_grid(population = LETTERS[1:3], age = 1:10, id = 1:3) %>% mutate(weight = rgamma(n(), 1) * 10) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = age, names_prefix = "weight at ", values_from = weight) %>%
  mutate(id = row_number())

df_long <- df %>% pivot_longer(starts_with("weight at "), names_to = "age", values_to = "weight") %>% 
  mutate(age = as.integer(str_extract(age, "\\d+")))

ggplot(df_long, aes(age, weight)) + geom_point() + facet_wrap(~ population)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-06-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>